# iframe with post request in child window works well in firefox, but not in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, post, iframe

I need to open child window with iframe and post request in it. Here js code

```
function SendPost() 
{
var params = "menubar=no,location=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes"
var ChildWin= window.open("", "ChildWin", params)
var form = ChildWin.document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute("method", "post");
form.setAttribute("id", "form");
form.setAttribute("name", "do_post");
form.setAttribute("action", "http://www.javascriptsource.com/");
form.setAttribute("target", "ext_app");

var hiddenField1 = ChildWin.document.createElement("input");
hiddenField1.setAttribute("type", "submit");
//hiddenField1.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
hiddenField1.setAttribute("value", "Submit");
form.appendChild(hiddenField1);
ChildWin.document.body.appendChild(form);

ifrm = ChildWin.document.createElement("iframe");
ifrm.setAttribute("sandbox", "allow-same-origin allow-scripts");
ifrm.setAttribute("id", "ext_app");
ifrm.setAttribute("width", "100%");
ifrm.setAttribute("height", "600");
ifrm.setAttribute("name", "ext_app");
ChildWin.document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
form.submit();
}
```

In firefox it works as required, but in IE it opens one more window and post request in it. I have no idea why this is happening and how to solve this problem for IE. Really need someone's help

Comment: Seem to work fine here in IE: http://jsfiddle.net/9x73G/ 

What version of IE are u using?